# Has Robert Frost ever written a poem that doesn't rhyme?

Tags: poetry, robert-frost

I know a few of Robert Frost's poems, though I'm not an expert, and I've noticed that they all have long and elaborate rhyme schemes.  Is this true for all of his poems?  Has he ever written a poem that didn't rhyme consistently (have a rhyme scheme)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, there are quite a few, including

- ["Mending Wall"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mending_Wall)
- ["The Death of the Hired Man"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Death_of_the_Hired_Man)
- ["Birches"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birches_(poem))
- ["Out, Out—"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out,_Out%E2%80%94)

That said, most of these do have a continuous meter. [Blank verse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blank_verse) has such a meter, while [free verse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_verse) does not. [Frost once said](http://www.math.grinnell.edu/~simpsone/Connections/Poetry/Forms/free1.html)

> I'd sooner write free verse as play tennis with the net down.

[A review by William O'Donnell](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25086971?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) says that Frost is "unequalled" by any British or American poets in the 19th century in his use of blank verse. In the early 20th century, such a structure was rejected by Ezra Pound and T. S. Eliot, although Frost continued writing the same way.

[Iambic pentameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iambic_pentameter), of course, permeates Frost's work. However, it is an odd, even informal variant. [A contemporary analysis](https://www.jstor.org/stable/801937?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) of Frost notes that ["The Runaway"](http://www.bartleby.com/155/12.html), while using the meter, is irregular even in the first few lines:

> **Once** when the **snow** of the **year** was be**gin**ning to **fall**,
>    We **stopped** by a **moun**tain **pas**ture to **say, “Whose colt?”**

The first line feels slightly smoother; the first, fourth, seventh, tenth and thirteenth syllables are all stressed. However, the second does not flow quite so well.

Comment: You can parse *The Runaway* so that it has five (irregular) feet per line. The second line just ends with a spondee, and I think it flows perfectly fine. And, despite the contemporary analysis's opinion, I would not call the meter even remotely iambic.

Comment: *Mending Wall* is indeed in loose iambic pentameter, showing that Frost could write iambic pentameter when he was trying to. Compare it with *The Runaway.*

Comment: @PeterShor I'm going to reread *The Runaway* and think about that. Thank you.

Comment: There's something odd about the quoted sentence “I'd sooner […] as […]”; in fact to my ear it sounds ungrammatical. Are you sure it's not something like “I'd just as soon […] as […]” or “I'd no sooner […] than […]” or something like that?